# Jersey 1.18 client with jaxb

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jersey-client

I am trying to use Jersey 1.18 client to get xml data from rest web service and then unmarshall it using JaxB. The problem is that I don't know how to forward data straight from Jersey into JaxB and the code looks a bit hideous.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://something.com");

    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
               .get(ClientResponse.class);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
        + response.getStatus());
    }

    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(output);
    Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I am using Jersey 1.18 because the latest version pulls a lot! of dependencies and I would like to make my "client" really light weight..

Comment: If your classes are properly annotated you should be able to do `Person person = response.getEntity(Person.class);`

Comment: You should really try the 2.10+ branch of Jersey. It's much cleaner and most of the dependencies you mention are probably not required in your application. See https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/2.0/modules-and-dependencies.html

Comment: when I added the 2.x to my POM.xml it pulled like 10jars where is jersey 1.18 is only 2 jars..

Comment: How could I achieve the same result in Jersey 2.x? These libraries are hard to use..

Comment: I wouldn't change anything until you get your solution working, I was just suggesting that you consider upgrading to Jersey 2.x when you can. The Jersey 2.x documentation is pretty good and they have a good guide on converting (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-1.x). Where you able to get your marshal/unmarshal problem resolved?